# Node/Express Project: Create and Sync a "Join Class/Model" to a Postgres Database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, associations, sequelize.js

I'm building a Node/Express/Postgres version of an app that I already built in Rails. I'm learning Node, so I figured I'd rebuild something that I know works.

For now, I'm dumping everything in one file (set up my database, defined my models, etc.), just to make sure I have everything set up correctly before I divvy them up into different files.

I set up my postgres database at the very top of the file, like so:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var db = new Sequelize('my_database_name', 'my_username', null, {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres',
});
```

With regard to my models, I have a Politician model:

```
var Politician = db.define("politician", {
  name: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
  politicalParty: {
   type: Sequelize.STRING
 }
});
```

A Category model:

```
var Category = db.define("category", {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  },
  keywords: {
    type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.TEXT)
  },
 });
```

And a join model of Politician and Category, called "Interest". Because Interest is a join model, it will have a "politicianId" and "categoryId" properties....but will those properties automatically generate in the database? And so, is this how I would define the Interest model, with no properties?

Interest Model:

```
 var Interest = db.define("interest")
```

Or, will I have to be specific, and create "politicianId" and "categoryId" properties? Like so:

Interest Model:

```
var Interest = db.define("interest", {
   id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  categoryId: {
   type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
   foreignKey: true
 },
 politicianId: {
   type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
   foreignKey: true
 }
});
```

Also, do I need the "foreignKey: true" bit? Or will it automatically know that those properties are foreign keys? Also, do I need the "id" property? I know models automatically create their own primary key "id"...but again, I've been at this for hours, looking at docs, and trying everything.

I then defined my associations (again, all of this is the same file):

```
Politician.belongsToMany(Category, {through: "Interest"});
Category.belongsToMany(Politician, {through: "Interest"});
```

[The Node/Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations) seems to suggest that defining those 2 associations above will automatically "create a new model called Interest with the equivalent foreign keys politicianId and categoryId." So, do I even need to define a "Interest" model? Also, do I need the follow associations to describe that Interest belongs to Politician and Category?

```
Interest.belongsTo(Politician);
Interest.belongsTo(Category);
```

If I don't write the associations saying that Interest belongs to Politican and Catetory, I don't get the "politicianId" and "categoryId" columns in the Interest table. Just the "id" and createdAt/updatedAt columns.

I then created an instance of Politician, Category, and Interest, to persist everything to the database, to see if everything is there and set up correctly:

Politician Object:

```
var politician1 = Politician.sync({force: true}).then(function(){
   return Politician.create(aPoliticianObjectDefinedInthisFile);
});
```

This works perfectly. I see this object in the politician table in the database.

Category Object:

```
var category1 = Category.sync({force: true}).then(function(){
  return Category.create(aCategoryObjectDefinedInThisFile);
 });
```

This works perfectly. I see this object in the category table in the database.

Here is what doesn't work. Creating an instance/object of Interest and synching it to the database. My thinking is, if I put integers as values, it will know that "politicianId: 1" means point to the politician object with an id of 1, and the same for "categoryId: 1". But when I write it as I have it below, the Interest table doesn't even show up in the Postgres database at all.

Interest Object:

```
Interest.sync({force: true}).then(function(){
  return Interest.create(
     {
      politicianId: 1,
      categoryId: 1
     }
   );
 });
```

However, when I create the object of Interest like this, with **no** properties defined, the Interest table appears in the database, along with the "politicianId" and "categoryId" columns, however, those columns are **empty**. The object's primary id is in there at 1, and the "createdAt" and "updatedAt" columns have data too. But the foreign key columns are blank.

Interest Object:

```
Interest.sync({force: true}).then(function()
   {
     return Interest.create(
       {
   // No properties defined. 
       }
    );
  }
);
```

Sorry for this long post, lol, but, in all: 
Am I creating the "Interest" model correctly? 
Am I writing the associations for "Interest" correctly? 
Do I even need to write associations for Interest, if I already have associations for its parent classes, Politican and Category defined?

In my Rails app, my associations for Politican and Category are like so:

Politician has_many interests 
Politican has_many categories through interests

Category has_many interests 
Category has_many politicians through interests

Interest belongs_to politician 
Interest belongs_to category

But I use the "belongsToMay" association in Node because I got an error telling me to do so.

Basically, I need to create an instance of Politician, an instance of Category, and an instance of Interest that has "politicianId" and "categoryId" columns that point to those aforementioned instances of those classes.

politicanABC -- id: 1 
categoryABC -- id: 1 
instanceABC -- id: 1; politicanId: 1 (referring to politicanABC); categoryid: 1 (referring to categoryABC).

My app is set up like that in Rails and works wonderfully. 
Help and thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define the Interest model if you are not going to add any additional fields. Sequelize will internally define the model and add all required fields once you do following:

```
Politician.belongsToMany(Category, {through: "Interest"});
Category.belongsToMany(Politician, {through: "Interest"});
```

Sync needs to run on database level and not on tables since Interest model is implicit at this point.

```
db.sync({force: true});
```

Sequelize will add relationship build methods on both Politician and Category instances. Category will have methods `addPolitician()`, `addPoliticians([])`, `setPoliticians([])`, `getPliticians()`. Politician instances will have similar functions to associate categories to them. You can connect these after create option is performed on both objects successfully.

```
Politician.create({name: 'John Doe', politicalParty: 'Nice Party'}) 
  .then(function(politician) { 
    Category.create({name: 'Nicers'}) 
     .then(function(category) { 
       politician.addCategory(category); 
     }); 
  });
```

You can also search and associate existing items using helper methods. Alternatively you can associate objects manually by accessing `db.models.Interest` model and running creates on it.

Comment: thank you faheem. i see an interest model in the database. however, when i write the "db.sync({force: true});" and then the "Politician.create({name: 'John Doe',..." as you have it,

Comment: sorry, i wasn't co

Comment: sorry i hadn't finished my comment the earlier 2 attempts, and i don't see an "edit" button. when i write the "db.sync({force: true});" and then the "Politician.create({name: 'John Doe',"......  i don't see any of that data in my database...there is nothing in the politician, category, or interest models. I also get this error when it runs: Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "Interest" does not exist

Comment: Create a new database and re-run the code. Everything is working perfectly fine for me. This is what I just checked -> http://pastebin.com/jdPLsjuj

Comment: So odd that this isn't working for me. Faheem, you created that instance of Politican and Category, but you didn't "sync" it to the database. How is it persisting to the database without you doing Politician.sync({force: true}).then(function(){
  return Politician.create(barackObama);
 });

Comment: I copied your code exactly, and still get the error :-/ even after creating a new node/express app and a new database. I should also add that when I look at the tables in the database, I see 3 tables: "Interest", "politicians" and "categories"...which is odd to me that "Interest" is the only singular table and also the only table that begins with a capital letter. meanwhile "politicians" and "categories" are lowercase and plural

Comment: I figured it out. The singular vs. plural thing had to do with out I was spelling "interest" in the association. I now have it like this: Politician.belongsToMany(Category, {through: "interests"});
Category.belongsToMany(Politician, {through: "interests"});

Comment: With regard to creating instances for the join table ("interest"), this works for the most part: Politician.sync({force: true}).then(function(){
 Politician.create(barackObama).then(function(politician) {

  Category.sync({force: true}).then(function(){
   Category.create(gunLaws).then(function(category) {

    politician.addCategory(category); 
   });
   });
 });
});

Comment: But if you check the database, it's a bit screw-y since for each politician, it's creating an instance of the category, which results in more categories than I need. How does the db.models.Interest work?

Comment: Below is how it works in Ruby. I'm trying to figure that out for Node/Express/Javascript: Politician.all.each do |politician|
  Category.all.each do |category|
    Interest.create(politician_id: politician.id, category_id: category.id)
  end
end

Comment: @DianaE. All your questions in the original post have been answered. For communities benefit, please create another question for other stuff. I will be sure to respond there.